# What should I do with nonexistent _bh RCU functions?

Tags: linux-kernel, rcu

There are many RCU functions that don't have a _bh counterpart.

Examples are:

- `list_entry_rcu()`
- `list_for_each_entry_rcu()`

Is this because...

1. they can be called from bottom halves just fine (think [`list_empty()` vs `list_empty_rcu()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rculist.h#L13))?

   - Does this mean I can use `rcu_read_lock()` and `rcu_read_lock_bh()` interchangeably in these cases?
2. no one has so far needed them (and therefore I's supposed to roll out my own version of them)?

[Rule 9 of the RCU checklist](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/RCU/checklist.txt#L291) says "in which case the matching `rcu_dereference()` primitive must be used in order to keep lockdep happy". So I guess the second option above is true. But then I find code that reads like this:

```
rcu_read_lock_bh();
c = __clusterip_config_find(clusterip);
```

And then, during [`__clusterip_config_find()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_CLUSTERIP.c?v=4.1#L131):

```
list_for_each_entry_rcu(c, &clusterip_configs, list) {
```

What is going on!? `list_for_each_entry_rcu()` uses `rcu_dereference_check()`, not `rcu_dereference_bh_check()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This true:

> 2. No one has so far needed them (and therefore I's supposed to roll out my own version of them).

More precise, there is so many RCU list traversal functions, so one decide to not include all their `_rcu_bh` counterpairs because of rare needs. But see below.

You cannot use `rcu_read_lock()` and `rcu_read_lock_bh` interchangably. But difference between `rcu_dereference` and `rcu_dereference_check` only in annotation: them both expanded to `__rcu_dereference_check()` macro call with different `c` argument.

So, implementation of `__clusterip_config_find` is correct from the processor's view, but may produce warnings when checker is enabled. (Of cource, every driver should tend to work without warnings).